# Bull spread problem

Tags: spread-options

I am new to finance math and I would like to know if my approach to this problem is correct

Consider the following three European call options, all with expiration at time $T$ = 1:

Option $A$ has strike option ($K$) of $10

Option $B$ has strike $15

Option $C$ has strike $20.

**Create a bull spread from options A and B.**

My understanding is that the spread for this would be buying A, because it is a lower K and selling B because it has a higher K.

Is there a better way to answer this?

Also, how would it work for 3 options, such as A, B,C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one way to think of it is to equate the traditional concept of "bullishness" to the modern BSM concept of "delta".

You buy the call at A, so you are "bullish" (positive Delta), now you sell the call at B. The Call at B is less "bullish" than A (smaller Delta) so when you sell it you "lower your bullishness, but stay overall bullish" (reduce Delta by subtracting a smaller number, so the overall Delta stays positive).

The opposite, sell A and buy B, would by definition be called a "bear spread" (negative overall Delta).

This way of thinking also generalizes to 3 options.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going through [Bull Spread Explained](http://www.theoptionsguide.com/bull-call-spread.aspx) to understand the bull spread better. Theoretically, your understanding is correct when you say that the spread would be buy A and sell B based on the strike price.

[This](https://www.fidelity.com/viewpoints/bull-call-spread) is also a good reference which help you understand the concept nicely.

In case of 3 instruments, I would think of doing either a buy-sell-buy or a sell-buy-sell strategy, which is typically how 3 legged instruments are traded.